# Check if the ThreadPool has any active threads

Tags: c#, threadpool

I'm writing a windows service that responds to IMAP push notifications. When a notification is received I queue a user work item using `ThreadPool`. (The method it invokes puts some things in a database and etc).

At some point I want to stop my service which will stop the `ThreadPool` from queuing additional threads and wait until there are no open threads that are doing work.

```
//Pseudo code
public void StopService()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (ThreadPool.ActiveThreads == 0)
        {
            //disconnect imap
            //stop service
        }
    }
}
```

Even better would be a way to tell the `ThreadPool` that I want to be notified that it has no active threads so that I don't have to poll it in a while loop.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365621/correct-way-of-checking-when-threadpool-threads-are-done) uses a thread safe counter which is one way to figure out if the ThreadPool has any open threads, but surely there must be a flag or some method/property off the `ThreadPool` class to determine this?

Comment: Wouldn't the code that you're running be an active thread in the ThreadPool?

Comment: Sure why not? I wrote Pseudo code for a reason, it's to help visualize what I wrote.

Comment: Well I was just thinking that it would be a reason why you'd never get inside of your `if` statement and stop your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you hook up all your individual work items to a `ManualResetEvent` then queue up all your work items in the `ThreadPool` and then call `WaitHandle.WaitAll(myResetEvents);` to wait until all of your work items are complete, then close your service down, etc.

**Program Flow**

1. Start Service
2. Start Listening
3. Queue Work Items
4. Stop Listening for new items
5. Wait for all items to finish -WaitHandle.WaitAll(allMyQueuedWorkitems)
6. Stop Service

Comment: So within the stop service method I should do `while(WaitHandle.WaitAll(...)){ //stop service //return;}`?

Comment: No, You would stop listening for new requests at some point, then wait for all existing queued items to complete, then call your close service method. See answer for updated program flow

Comment: Oh I see, I call stop service method and at that point I stop listening then put `WaitHandle.WaitAll` and after that goes my code to actually stop the service. It appears that by calling`WaitAll` won't execute the code after it until it's done.

Comment: Yes, by calling `WaitAll()`, it will block your main thread until all items you have queued have finished.